# Internal server error encountered when running flask app modwsgi error

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run my first ever flask app on an apache server but I am receiving these errors saying there is no module called FlaskApp. I am not sure why it is saying this because I have my `__init.py__` inside that directory.

I am using Python 2.7.12+

Here is my filesystem:

```
FlaskApp/  
FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi  
FlaskApp/FlaskApp/
```

Inside my second FlaskApp directory there is an `init.py` as well as a `venv/` for a virtual environment as well as a `static/` and `templates/` directories.

This second FlaskApp directory should be a module because of the `init.py` but it does not see it as so.

Here is my Apache config file for my FlaskApp: FlaskApp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName 104.236.161.79
                ServerAdmin youemail@email.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my init.py :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "This is a test.?"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here is my error.log for apache:

```
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.777285 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17216:tid 140131998578432] [client 73.222.116.44:51594] mod_wsgi (pid=17216): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python $
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.777357 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17216:tid 140131998578432] [client 73.222.116.44:51594] mod_wsgi (pid=17216): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.777383 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17216:tid 140131998578432] [client 73.222.116.44:51594] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.777408 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17216:tid 140131998578432] [client 73.222.116.44:51594]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.777494 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17216:tid 140131998578432] [client 73.222.116.44:51594]     from FlaskApp import app as application
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.777521 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17216:tid 140131998578432] [client 73.222.116.44:51594] **ImportError: No module named FlaskApp**
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.883438 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17217:tid 140132178011904] [client 73.222.116.44:51595] mod_wsgi (pid=17217): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python $
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.883502 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17217:tid 140132178011904] [client 73.222.116.44:51595] mod_wsgi (pid=17217): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., re$
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.883526 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17217:tid 140132178011904] [client 73.222.116.44:51595] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://104.236.161.79/
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.883563 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17217:tid 140132178011904] [client 73.222.116.44:51595]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://104.236.161.79/
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.883635 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17217:tid 140132178011904] [client 73.222.116.44:51595]     from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: //104.236.161.79/
[Fri Mar 17 00:11:09.883671 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 17217:tid 140132178011904] [client 73.222.116.44:51595] ImportError: No module named FlaskApp, referer: //104.236.161.79/
```

Comment: Where had you installed the Flask package, direct into a Python installation, or a Python virtual environment? If it was a virtual environment, how is your Apache configuration for mod_wsgi set up? If into a Python installation, is your mod_wsgi installation actually compiled for that specific Python version/installation?

Comment: How have you configured the Apache configuration for mod_wsgi to tell it where your application code is located. Python in an embedded system like mod_wsgi will not automatically look in the current directory of the WSGI script file and needs to be told to look there.

Comment: Hi Graham, thank you for the response. I forgot to put my filesystem in my post so sorry about that. I am going to edit my post to put that in

Comment: It is the mod_wsgi configuration from Apache configuration file that need to see.

Comment: The tutorial I followed had me install flask inside a virtual environment which is my venv/ directory inside my FlaskApp/FlaskApp/ directory

Comment: Hi, I am going to edit my post to add my FlaskApp.conf which is the Apache config file.

Comment: Read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html It explains how to setup mod_wsgi for a virtual environment. Also ensure you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode and then use ``python-path`` option to tell mod_wsgi where your application code is.

Comment: Okay I will look into that, thank you. Based off my updated post, do you have an idea about why it isn't working?

Comment: I already told you, you need to tell mod_wsgi where your application code is. It DOES NOT look in the directory where the WSGI script file is automatically. You need to tell it to look there for Python packages/modules. That is what ``python-path`` option to daemon mode directory ``WSGDaemonProcess`` is for.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will figure it out

Comment: Alright I fixed it, thank you